# Can not use or detect global .net tools on Linux

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have installed the `dotnet-ef` and a number of other packages but for some reason, I can't use them.

I added `$HOME/.dotnet/tools` as shown here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/troubleshoot-usage-issues

but running `dotnet tool list` still shows no packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that `dotnet tool list` command checks for local tools by default. Try `dotnet tools list -g` to look for globally installed tools. Make sure your PATH contains the global tools folder location before running the installed tool. You can check your PATH by running `echo $PATH`. You can also check globally installed tools by running `dotnet tool list --tool-path $HOME/.dotnet/tools`. Following steps work for me:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet/tools"
dotnet tool list -g
dotnet-ef
```

HTH

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please accept the answer if it solved your issue.